# laravel migration change column type double to string : down function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to modify column type from `double(8,2)` to `varchar`.

Since as mentioned in the doc, it doesn't allow `double` to change, so I tried using `raw` statement.

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE dmf_product_match_unmatches MODIFY s_price VARCHAR(191)');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE dmf_product_match_unmatches MODIFY r_price VARCHAR(191)');
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
}
```

So my question is what do I need to mention in `down` method?

Comment: nothing in ```down``` method just let it empty

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I am importing data from some other source to my db table. And this other source has all sorts of characters to that field like `$` and all. so

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations check this..

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I am even more confused now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not write code in down method, at the rollback time s_price and r_price will have VARCHAR(191) but not double(8,2) in schema.

The below down() method will revert s_price and r_price to DOUBLE(8,2) when you run

> php artisan migrate:rollback

```
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE dmf_product_match_unmatches MODIFY s_price DOUBLE(8,2)');
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE dmf_product_match_unmatches MODIFY r_price DOUBLE(8,2)');
}
```